# Arduino, exit status 1. Can't compile for Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

```
#include <LedControl.h>

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

This is my code: with `LedControl.h` it gives me exit status 1, can't compile for Arduino Uno. Please help.

If I remove the `#include` it works normally.

Also Arduino says that the library has been installed.

What I have tried (but didn't work):

Re-installing the library.
Re-downloading Arduino.

Comment: "Exit status 1" means "there was an error". You forgot to tell us what that error is.

Comment: @Majenko  "exit status 1 can't compile to arduino uno" it's literally in the title

Comment: No, that is NOT the error message. Paste in the entirety of what is in the output pane if you don't understand what an error message is.

Comment: [Don't cross post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) You already [asked this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50392946).

Comment: @gre_gor I was told on stackoverflow to ask my question here

Comment: @nordinleije Did you check [the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)?

Answer (score 1):

I tried compiling your code with Arduino 1.6.12. As you found, without the #include, it compiles OK. With the #include, it fails. Here is the error message I got:

```
/var/folders/bl/s5kzhm3s0lb2rcvp3md8c7040000gp/T/untitled1814027053.tmp/sketch_may17a/sketch_may17a.ino:1:24: fatal error: LedControl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <LedControl.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno 115.2.
```

The error - at least in my case - is that the library, LedControl.h, was not found. Try to find out why not.

> also aruino says that the library has been installed.

It's easy to check: "Installing" library `foo.h`, only means your sketchbook folder contains a library folder called `libraries` (all lower case); `libraries` contains a folder `foo`; and `foo` contains the file `foo.h` and any other files necessary for that library, such as a `foo.cpp` if needed:

```
- Sketchbook - libraries - foo
                             foo.h
                             foo.cpp
                             anything.else.you.like
```

Update:

The library documentation [is on github](http://wayoda.github.io/LedControl/) and has links to some sample code. Sorry I can't be more help - I haven't used the library or those LED devices.

Comment: thank you for you anwer, could you please also show how to use this library properly I kinda need it, because I use a MAX7219 LED.

Comment: `how to use this library properly` ... don't get ahead of yourself .... you don't even know if you have the library installed